# How do I omit a value in typescript union type

Tags: typescript

I have a type:

```
export type Example = ExampleOne | ExampleTwo | ExampleThree;
```

How do I create a new type `ExampleX` which only contains `ExampleOne` or `ExampleTwo`?

I tried:

```
export type ExampleX = Omit<Example, 'ExampleThree'>;
```

But that doesn't work?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You're looking for [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) rather than `Omit`:

> **`Exclude<UnionType, ExcludedMembers>`**
>
> Constructs a type by excluding from UnionType all union members that are assignable to ExcludedMembers.

*(And you don't want the quotes.)*

So:

```typescript
export type ExampleX = Exclude<Example, ExampleThree>;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDYQPIDtoF4oDeCAXFAM7ABOAllgOYC+A3AFCiSyIroAqA7gHso+AgCNSFGvWZtw0eMjQQeAC0oQ8hAMYSqtRqxYB6AFQQ4YAZWAmj7eVyXDOi9NmgAfF92WCoXhR9VdQhDU3NLa1soe28lAA1neC1UAFcAEwgAHkClABo43jUNAD5WIyMoKuqamoA9QCQiJuaWqBUBADcIShiVajIYoTINQswcf1H+ASA)